# my app works perfectly on web but dosen't work on android

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

After upgrading to flutter 2.10 had some problems with the kotlin version and solved it but it still dosen't work showing me a white screen on the emulator

errors i recieved :

```
W/DynamiteModule(28033): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(28033): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(28033): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/m.example.femv(28033): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty  (28033): uid=10126(com.example.femv2) AsyncTask #1 identical 1 line
I/m.example.femv(28033): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/nativeloader(28033): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
W/ProviderInstaller(28033): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/NativeCrypto(28033): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
I/TetheringManager(28033): registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.femv2
W/m.example.femv(28033): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller(28033): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
```

after i hot restart :

```
W/DynamiteModule(28033): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(28033): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(28033): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller(28033): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
```

The app still works on the web perfectly

Comment: Are you sure Google services are right setup on the Android side?